# $.ajax passing multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

For some reason passing parameters using ajax is a real problem for me. I checked all of the questions regarding parameters and found the following as the correct way to pass parameters:

```
           var username = $("#email_0000").val(),
                password = $("#password_0000").val(),
                func = 'emailexists',
                bValid = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "php/ajax.php",
                data: {
                    func:func,
                    email:username
                },

                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

The following is my php code:

```
    <?php
    $func = $_REQUEST['func'];

    echo var_dump($_GET);

    switch($func) {
        case 'emailexists':
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
            echo 'Email address is='.$email;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
```

The alert is showing the following:

```
    array(1){
     ["func"]=>
     string(11)"emailexists"
    }
    Email address is=
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but if someone has a clue I would appreciate it. Am I missing something in the "head" tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="1">
<!--Stylesheets-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dhaStyle.css">
<!--JavaScripts -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/DHA_forms.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help, regards, Rich

Comment: I think data needs to be a serialized string instead of a javascritp object

Comment: do a `console.log(username)` in your javascript and see what it contains, it looks like you're just getting an empty string

Comment: @Ejay - nope, objects are fine.

Comment: @Ejay - In the world of jQuery it needs to be an Object.

Comment: Your dump of the GET scope confirms that 'email' doesn't exist.

Comment: @adeneo `data. Type: PlainObject or String. Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string` needed a trip to docs :)

Comment: Yes, you can basically only send string with XMLHttpRequest, but jQuery accepts objects, arrays and just about anything, and converts to string.

Comment: unless you show us the markup for the input fields, this is totally fine except you are not getting the email value from the input field.

Comment: Okay, a rookie mistake. If I would have included the form you would have seen the ID="EMAIL_0001" and would have pointed out that I must maintain case sensitivity. As I lay here in my own bile, I will hopefully be a better student of js, jquery, php, etc.